# Laravel seems to be looking for the old view

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I have created a new view called "home" and am trying to route there from the "/" root.

code:

```
Route::get('/', function()
{
    return View::make('home');
});
```

Unforunately i am getting the "something went wrong error" when i load the page.

This is what i see in my logs:

```
[2014-11-09 18:15:35] production.ERROR: exception 'InvalidArgumentException' with message 'View [hello] not found.'
```

The previous view name was 'hello.php'. The current one is 'home.blade.php'.

Not sure what is going on here so any help is appreciated.

Cheers!!

Comment: Yes, happens sometimes. Try clearing the cache folder it makes. (btw hello.blade.php and hello.php are both internally called "hello". The .blade part just tells Blade how you want to render it.)

Comment: Hey thanks. Where do i find this cache folder?

Comment: @Tapha, it's in `app/storage/views`.

Comment: You should enable `debug` in `app/config/app.php` for easier debugging.